# Switch to Multiple Directory for loop Array

Tags: bash

I'm Trying to switch multiple directory based on input as array, Note I'm passing the two directory path and assign into variable name start_dir.

When I'm passing directory path as a single input I can able to get the output as we expected.
When I'm passing directory path as a double input I'm not able to get the expected output.

```
└─# tree
.
├── Inbound
│   └── Lambda
│       ├── app-inbound
│       │   ├── inbound-primary.py
│       │   └── requirements.txt
│       └── app-inbound
│           ├── inbound-primary.py
│           └── requirements.txt

└─# tree
.
├── Outbound
│   └── Lambda
│       ├── app-Outbound
│       │   ├── outbound-primary.py
│       │   └── requirements.txt
│       └── app-outbound
│           ├── Outbound-primary.py
│           └── requirements.txt
```

```
#!/bin/bash

start_dir=(/root/Outbound/Lambda/  /root/Inbound/Lambda)

for d in "${start_dir[@]}"/*/ ; do
   echo "switch directory"
   cd "$d" || exit
   echo "Entring into location"
   for sub_dir in "${d[@]}" ; do
     echo "$sub_dir"
     zip -r "${sub_dir%/}".zip "$sub_dir"
   done
done
```

Comment: `d` is not an array, it's the directory that you just changed to. What do you expect `${d[@]}` to be?

Comment: I think you want `for sub_dir in */` to loop through all the subdirectories of the current directory.

Comment: I want to be switch into cd $d (its a sub-directory) then i need make zip file

Comment: You already have that with `cd "$d"`. Why do you think`for sub_dir in "${d[@]}"` is right? That's for looping over the contents of an array.

Comment: That's right even i tried without having cd "$d", but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
   for sub_dir in "${d[@]}" ; do
```

`$d` is not an array, so you can't expand it with `"${d[@]}"`. To get all the subdirectory names in the current directory, user `*/`. So change that line to:

```
   for sub_dir in */ ; do
```